# How to prevent accidental history swipe back navigation with HTML games?

Tags: javascript, android, html, gesture, back

I am developing a website that has games on it. The website is also playable on mobile in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

They are canvas browser games where you use your finger to play the games.

Because the canvas is square, it often takes up the entire viewport width of the mobile device.

It is very common to place your fingers all over the screen and do various swiping gestures while playing the game. As a result, sometimes my users accidentally swipe back and the game ends.

That is, they may place their finger on the left or right side of the screen and move it inwards, and the mobile browser detects this as a "back swipe" gesture, and immediately closes the game and goes back to the previous page.

This is *extremely* frustrating to my users. Is there any way to disable this? I searched here and none of the solutions for "preventing browser back" seem to work, and making the game fullscreen isn't really an option either, as the games are meant to be played while in view of the rest of the website (they're minigames).

Also, I do not want to use the `onbeforeunload` alert box either, because it is very annoying to have this alert box pop up while playing the minigames. I would just like to disable the back swipe gesture while they're playing these minigames, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding event listeners for touchevents using Javascript. This will be used to intercept the swipe actions and prevent the swipe from triggering the swipe-back action. Handle the `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events for your browser.

Example:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

let xBot= null; 
let yBot = null;

function handleTouchStart(e) {                                         
    xBot = e.touches[0].clientX;                                      
    yBot = e.touches[0].clientY;                                      
};                                                

function handleTouchMove(e) {
    if (!xBot || !yBot ) {
        return;
    }

    let xTop = e.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    let yTop = e.touches[0].clientY;

    let xDiff = xBot - xUp;
    let yDiff = yBot - yUp;

    if (Math.abs(xDiff) > Math.abs(yDiff)) {/*most significant*/
        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            /* left swipe */ 
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevents swipe back action
        } else {
            /* right swipe */
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevents swipe back action
        }                       
    } 
    /* reset values */
    xBot = null;
    yBot = null;                                             
};
```

I also suggest you use iFrames,
Try embedding the game canvas within the iFrame. This will be a basis to create a sandboxed environment that will make the swipe behavior stop propagating on your browser.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried just doing `document.addEventListener('touchstart', e => e.preventDefault(), false);` and `document.addEventListener('touchmove', e => e.preventDefault(), false);` and even that doesn't stop the gesture from invoking the back action. I've never used iFrames before but I'll look into those, thanks

Comment: yes i believe it will work, i use it to prevent default touch actions, but doing it may cause some unwanted side effects to your browser like unscrollable scroll, and other functions.

if you want to selectively prevent swipe-back gesture then  you need to implement more complex touch event logic for that. like listening to touch events on specific region where your canvas appears. 

you may also use the pause and resume. if you really cant prevent the swipe back gesture. In this way you prevent unwanted swipe back and avoid inconvenience.

Comment: tastyNoodle: sorry, just to clarify, you believe an iFrame will work? or touch events? Also, I don't understand, wouldn't the user just perform the swipe back gesture on the parent page (the one that isn't an iFrame), and then the entire page would be swiped back regardless?